# CodeIgniter : No input file specified : PATH_INFO : $_GET

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, get, pathinfo

when I use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|favicon\.ico|robots\.txt|class|style|js)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

in .htaccess and:

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = "PATH_INFO";
```

in config.php
the result is:
MY WINDOWS SERVER says: everything OK and MY LINUX SERVER says **No input file specified**

so I change .htaccess that way:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|favicon\.ico|robots\.txt|class|style|js)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

and in config.php:

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = "QUERY_STRING";
```

than:
everything works BUT $_GET not!!! how can I use $_GET with such settings? simple:

```
parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $_GET);
```

doesn't work now

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using fastcgi PHP which means you should take a look at CI's user guide for troubleshooting: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/troubleshooting.html

-- EDIT --

I misunderstood the question. Enabling querystrings should be done through the CI config.
Look at the bottom of this user guide page: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html

Comment: yes, and I can't set cgi.fix_pathinfo to 0; what probably couse the problem. setting $config['index_page'] = "index.php?" doesn't make any difference; everything works without this - the question is - how to use/implement $_GET now?

Answer (score 0):

solved... I used this:

```
$ru = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
parse_str(substr($ru,strpos($ru,'?')+1), $_GET);
```

now I can use $_GET again

Comment: That's not how you should do it - look at the bottom of this page: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html or at my updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to CodeIgniter Reactor 2.0, $_GET works on most installations. 2.0.1 will be out this week which has even better support.